# asp.net plotting empty points

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 1 data serie plotted on a chart.  However, there are periods where there are no data and this causes the chart to draw a line from the end of 1 data point to the start of the next data point.  Is there a way to plot empty points or insert breaks in the line chart?

I'm using a databound datesource.

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to insert the dates that does not have data into your collection.

Probably you have a collection that looks like:

```
[
 { Date: 02/02/2016, Value: 100},
 { Date: 02/03/2016, Value: 123},
 { Date: 02/05/2016, Value: 5},
 { Date: 02/06/2016, Value: 200},
]
```

As you can see, day 4 is missing. You'll have to add it with value 0 (zero).

```
[
 { Date: 02/02/2016, Value: 100},
 { Date: 02/03/2016, Value: 123},
 { Date: 02/04/2016, Value: 0},
 { Date: 02/05/2016, Value: 5},
 { Date: 02/06/2016, Value: 200},
]
```

That was just an example, you'll have to do it when you get your data.

Regards,

Comment: I don't have a data collection.  The data is from a sql data table.

Comment: @KadawTomtom You've shown no code so no one has any idea what kind of objects you're using.  The point is you need to use "0" values so the graph plots the data as "0" on the y-axis, as suggested by this answer.